# Getting mime types array in Firefox Add-on script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

I'm trying to get MIME types list on a firefox extension side.

There is **navigator** object in browser JavaScript context.
It has **mimeTypes** property - list of MIME types recognized by the browser.
I need to get that list in add-on script using Add-On SDK or XPCOM.
How can I do that? I cannot find any appropriate methods in XPCOM or SDK.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It has mimeTypes property - list of MIME types recognized by the browser.

No, it isn't - it is merely the list of MIME types that have a plugin (Flash & Co.) registered for them. If you need to get plugin information I would normally recommend using [`nsIPluginHost.getPluginTags()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPluginHost#getPluginTags%28%29). Unfortunately, the plugin tags don't have information on MIME types associated with the plugins.

So you cannot avoid getting hold of a `navigator` object that is only available in the window context. You can do that using [`page-worker` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/packages/addon-kit/page-worker.html):

```js
require("page-worker").Page({
  contentScript: "var result = [];" +
                 "for (var i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; i++)" +
                   "result.push(navigator.mimeTypes[i].type);" +
                 "self.postMessage(result);",
  contentURL: "about:blank",
  onMessage: function(mimeTypes) {
    // Do something with the MIME types
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are there any sirializer constraints? I cannot transmit object **navigator** itself, for example.

Comment: @Dmitry: It's a [JSON serializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).